# How to post file media type of uploaded file when using Uploadify and JQuery with ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, uploadify

I am saving a file to sql server 2008 using uploadify in an ASP.NET MVC 3 web app. I need to get the internet media type, e.g. application/msword, application/pdf, etc., of the file the user uploads and post it along with some other information to a controller action. If not the media type, at least the file extension.

Here's some of the code

View - javascript section

```
$('#flyer').uploadify({
            'uploader': '/Flash/uploadify.swf',
            'script': '/File/Upload',
            'cancelImg': '/Content/images/cancel.png',
            'buttonText': 'Select File',
            'folder': '/Uploads',
            'auto': true,
            'sizeLimit': 10485760,
            'scriptData': { 'UserID': @Model.UserID, 'Type': 'Flyer' },
            'fileExt': '*.doc;*.docx;*.rtf;*.pdf',
            'fileDesc': 'Word Documents',
            'onComplete': function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
                var resp = jQuery.parseJSON( response );
                if( !resp.success ){
                    alert( resp.message );
                } else {
                    $("#flyerLink").show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Controller action method header

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase FileData, int UserID, string Type)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: no need to post the mediafile type. You can check in your controller for the content type `FileData.ContentType`

Answer (score 0):

`HttpPostedFileBase` includes the mime-type via the `ContentType` property:

[MSDN - HttpPostedFileBase.ContentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.contenttype.aspx)

Comment: Oops, I was just looking at solutions related to uploadify. Unfortunately, this is only giving application/octet-stream as the content type but it does give the file name which has the extension. Do you have an idea why I would get that media type versus application/msword?